# ¿Como ejecutar una función al deschequear un input, jquery?

Tags: jquery

De la siguiente forma obtengo una lista con sus respectivos checkbox

```
var cupones_bienvenida_todos = $('.cupones_bienvenida_todos');
                        var tipoCupon ='';

                        $.each(response.data, function (i) {
                            if (response.data[i].Tipo_cupon == 1){
                                tipoCupon = "Cupón de 60%";
                            }
                            else if(response.data[i].Tipo_cupon == 1){
                                tipoCupon = "Cupón de 80%";
                            }
                            else{
                                tipoCupon = "Cupón de 100%";
                            }


                              $('<tr class="cupones"/>')
                                    .append($('<td/>').addClass('nuevo-td')
                                        .append($('<label/>').addClass('label-radio item-content').text(response.data[i].Cod_Cliente +" - "+response.data[i].Nombre)))
                                    .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td').text(tipoCupon))
                                    .append('<div class="cod_cupon" style="display:none">' + response.data[i].Identificador + '</div>')
                                    .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td')
                                                .append($('<label/>').addClass('label-checkbox item-content')
                                                            .append('<input type="checkbox" name="cupon_check" class="cupon_check" value="' + response.data[i].Identificador + '"/>')
                                                            .append($('<span/>').addClass('item-media').append('<i class="icon icon-form-checkbox"></i>'))))
                                    .appendTo(cupones_bienvenida_todos);
                                 if (cantidad_llaves === 0) {
                                    $('.cupon_check').prop('disabled', true)
                                }
                            });
```

y de esta forma ejecuto una funcion al chequear el input:

```
$('.cupones_bienvenida_todos').on('click','.cupon_check:checked', function(e){

});
```

Por ejemplo si chequeo un input, accede a la funcion anterior, pero como puedo ejecutar una funcion al momento de deschequear ese mismo input.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Simplemente puedes evaluar el evento `change` del elemento con la clase `.cupon_check`; con este evento puedes evaluar cuando esta `checked` y cuando no, hice un ejemplo para que te guies:

```js
const funcion1 = () => {
  alert("Función cuando estoy checked")
}

const funcion2 = () => {
  alert("Función cuando NO estoy checked")
}

$(".cupon_check").on("change", function(e){
  
  ($(this).is(":checked")) ? funcion1() : funcion2();
  console.log($(this).is(":checked"))

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="cupon_check">
```

Con tu evento **click**:

```js
const funcion1 = () => {
  alert("Función cuando estoy checked")
}

const funcion2 = () => {
  alert("Función cuando NO estoy checked")
}

$(".cupones_bienvenida_todos").on("click", function(){

   ($(".cupon_check").is(":checked")) ? funcion1() : funcion2();
   console.log($(".cupon_check").is(":checked"))

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="cupon_check">
<input type="button" class="cupones_bienvenida_todos" value="Probar">
```

Espero te funcione.

Comment: por alguna extraña razon no ejecuta ninguna funcion.

Comment: Estas seguro? lo estoy probando y funciona, refresca a ver

Comment: Si, sera que debo utilizar la clase .cupones_bienvenida_todos

Comment: Tu dices que te esta fallando es en tu código no? pense que hablabas del código que deje corriendo aqui en stackoverflow. Todos los checkbox deberia de tener la clase `.cupon_check`, voy a editar mi ejemplo para quizas adaptarlo aun mas a tu código

Comment: Ya lo modifique, fijate como coloque el evento onchage

Comment: De esta forma ejecuta la funcion: `$(".cupones_bienvenida_todos").on("change", '.cupon_check', function(e){}`, solo que al chequearlo me lanza el error **Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined**

Comment: OK dame un min voy a modificar nuevamente mi respuesta

Comment: Listo ya modifique y agregue un evento click, asi deberia de quedar suerte

Comment: ni idea porque me sigue saliendo el mensaje **`Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined**

Answer (score 3):

Puedes asociar el evento change al input, así obtendrás los cambios en el input

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#check').on('change',function(event){
    $('#textChecked').text('Checked: ' + event.target.checked);
  })
})
```

```html
   


 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="check"> click

<p id="textChecked">Checked: </p>
```